# Recovering the settings of Preview app from a previous installation

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I made a backup of my entire drive before performing a clean install of Mac OS X.

Now, having done the fresh installation, I'm restoring the settings that my apps had on my previous installation. I've so far been successful with most of the apps, but now I'm having trouble with Preview.app. It doesn't want to restore the condition it was in in my previous installation (i.e. all the PDF documents that were open and the pages they were open at).

I've already copied all the possibly relevant files from `~/Library/Group Containers`, `~/Library/Containers`, `~/Library/Application Support` and `~/Library/Preferences`, but to no avail. Preview.app still launches like it's never opened any files.

Can I achieve what I'm trying to do? If so, how would I go about this?

Comment: Check `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState` - which is actually an alias to `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState`, so you might need to chase round a bit to locate/recreate the link.

Comment: @Tetsujin Everything up to  `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library` is there, but there is no folder `Saved Application State` there.